# JUnit test in Android Studio: NoClassDefFoundError: junit/textui/ResultPrinter

Tags: exception, junit, android-studio

I have a fresh installation of Android Studio with a new Android project. I created one JUnit test class but I cannot run it:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\java" -ea -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\android-studio\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\android-studio\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\android-studio\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;D:\Dev\android-sdks\platforms\android-21\android.jar;D:\Dev\android-sdks\platforms\android-21\data\res;D:\Dev\android-sdks\tools\support\annotations.jar;d:\myapp\mobile\build\intermediates\classes\debug;D:\jon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.j256.ormlite\ormlite-android\4.48\afa06f539a4026c10b247386312aa67404b80a16\ormlite-android-4.48.jar;D:\jon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-io\commons-io\2.0.1\7ffdb02f95af1c1a208544e076cea5b8e66e731a\commons-io-2.0.1.jar;D:\Dev\android-sdks\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-annotations\21.0.2\support-annotations-21.0.2.jar;D:\jon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.j256.ormlite\ormlite-core\4.48\e579bd2905d0399af5029aaaf9817d5fa0ca88a5\ormlite-core-4.48.jar;d:\myapp\mobile\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\21.0.2\res;d:\myapp\mobile\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\21.0.2\libs\internal_impl-21.0.2.jar;d:\myapp\mobile\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\21.0.2\classes.jar;D:\jon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.dagger\dagger\1.2.2\e8f912ee19ad84958510883ea191135276b091f8\dagger-1.2.2.jar;D:\jon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.inject\javax.inject\1\6975da39a7040257bd51d21a231b76c915872d38\javax.inject-1.jar;D:\jon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.androidannotations\androidannotations-api\3.2\89b33bb1e996eb2c4089f79d1b8651c71fe8e2d1\androidannotations-api-3.2.jar;D:\jon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup\otto\1.3.5\7941cd2c2c8ec006800d75c35f8a9dacf892ab93\otto-1.3.5.jar;d:\myapp\mobile\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\6.1.71\classes.jar;d:\myapp\mobile\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\6.1.71\res;d:\myapp\mobile\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\net.danlew\android.joda\2.5.1\classes.jar;d:\myapp\mobile\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\net.danlew\android.joda\2.5.1\res;D:\jon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.robobinding\robobinding\0.8.9\c6b50ddd9e741a7c8e54b56ac7057a66312a3e11\robobinding-0.8.9-with-dependencies.jar;d:\myapp\javamail\build\intermediates\classes\debug" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 com.example.MyUnitTest
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/textui/ResultPrinter
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.textui.ResultPrinter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 3 more
```

It's my first attempt to use Android Studio and to do JUnit tests. So sorry if the solution is obvious.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516289)?

Comment: Hmm yes, I have to run an "Android Test" instead of a "Unit Test". However, I am still confused in terms of Java and Android testing concepts. I think I need a few good tutorials.

Comment: Currently it seems impossible to run basic unit tests in Android Studio. Google only implemented the "intrumented" testing, with the whole Android environment. There is an issue open on that since last year https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75043

Answer (score 2):

Following solution worked for me in windows:

1) in the environment variables add a new "system variables"
ANDROID_SDK_HOME=D:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows (select your home directory of android sdk )

2) modify system variables Path, add "%Android_SDK_HOME%\tools;"

Comment: This actually worked, even when trying to run Android-dependent unittests (which needs to be enabled in the gradle file according to google) by including android{ ...testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }...}