# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/textui/ResultPrinter After updating to Yosemite

Tags: java, android, junit, android-studio

I recently updated my system from Mavericks (OSX) to Yosemite. I use to be able to right click on a test and run it. Now I get the exception

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -ea -Didea.launcher.port=7541 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/Users/michael.cameron/Code/Android/sdk/platforms/android-21/android.jar:/Users/michael.cameron/Code/Android/sdk/platforms/android-21/data/res:/Users/michael.cameron/Code/Android/darxstudios/TheChefsCodex/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug:/Users/michael.cameron/Code/Android/darxstudios/TheChefsCodex/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/classes.jar:/Users/michael.cameron/Code/Android/darxstudios/TheChefsCodex/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/res:/Users/michael.cameron/Code/Android/darxstudios/TheChefsCodex/app/libs/ParseCrashReporting-1.8.0.jar:/Users/michael.cameron/Code/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/21.0.3/support-annotations-21.0.3.jar:/Users/michael.cameron/Code/Android/darxstudios/TheChefsCodex/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/21.0.3/res:/Users/michael.cameron/Code/Android/darxstudios/TheChefsCodex/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/21.0.3/classes.jar:/Users/michael.cameron/Code/Android/darxstudios/TheChefsCodex/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/21.0.3/libs/internal_impl-21.0.3.jar:/Users/michael.cameron/Code/Android/darxstudios/TheChefsCodex/app/libs/Parse-1.8.0.jar:/Users/michael.cameron/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.parse.bolts/bolts-android/1.1.4/129874135e6081269ace2312092031558865de12/bolts-android-1.1.4.jar:/Users/michael.cameron/Code/Android/darxstudios/TheChefsCodex/app/libs/bolts-android-1.1.4.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 com.darxstudios.thechefscodex.ApplicationTest
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/textui/ResultPrinter
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.textui.ResultPrinter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 3 more
```

it may also be related to when i tap the open Android Studio icon in my Dock i get the error no JVM was found but i can open it via Terminal no problem.

This is the same as a brand new android studio project with the default applicationTest trying to run.

Comment: You will need to add the specified class on your java program classpath before running the program.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891564/how-to-run-unit-tests-with-android-studio) thread?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So two things

First, if you try to open Android Studio on Yosemite upgrade and it says "No JVM found" you need to install the java 6 for osx [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) as Android requires java 1.6 and not java 1.6+.

Second, The Exception I found was caused because it was trying to run JUnit as if I wanted to run through java standard console instead of with Android.

Do not use the Java test that contains a black with arrows, use the unit tests within a Android Tests and delete all uses of the JUnit configuration.

[image]

Your configuration should look like this, then you can right click on single tests and run them like normal.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As of the release of Android Studio 1.1.0 (on Feb 18 2015), it is now possible to run standard JUnit tests in Android Studio on local JVM for as long as the code under test isn't calling Android API. Please follow the instructions in [this guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support) for more info.